# Multiple use a class

Tags: arrays, class

I am creating a game using an array, I have my Hunter class which looks somewhat like this ;

```
 public static int x= 11;
public static int y =11;
public static String name = "H";`
```

And a method for its path using x and y.

I have declared hunter as an array in my board (2d array) class this way;

```
public Hunter hunters[] = new Hunter[5];
```

and the position of a hunter is declared in the board class as ;

```
a2[Hunter.x][Hunter.y] = Hunter.name;
```

Question: I want 5 hunters to appear on the board, how do I use the array to spawn additional 4 hunters? Thanks.

Comment: Your question isn't a matter of multiple-inheritance so the tag isn't right. It is simply a matter of static VS instance state. Simply remove the static modifier to your variables and you can instantiate multiple hunters with different states.

Answer (score 1):

you created your array fine all you need to do is use it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    a2[hunters[i].x][hunters[i].y] = hunters[i].name
}
```

also, you need to make your Hunter members non-static

```
class Hunter
{
    private int x, y;

    public void setLocation(int x_, int y_)
    {
        x = x_; y = y_;
    }
}
```

you get the idea :)

Comment: I have removed static from my code completely, however in my Main method, it still cannot execute non-static methods from a static context(even though my main method is now 'public void main(String[] args)', does the main method is automatically static?

Answer (score 1):

The `static` keyword (assuming you are using C++, java, C#) means that the variable is shared among all instances of the `Hunter` class. To allow each `Hunter` to have its own position, remove the `static` keyword and initialize them with a constructor.

I'll assume you're using Java bases on your use of `String`:

```
public class Hunter {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public String name;

    public Hunter(int x, int y, string name) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Then to initialize 5 you would do

```
int numHunters = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < numHunters; i ++) {
    hunters[i] = new Hunter(/* put x and y and name here */);
}
```

You can then use them to populate the board:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numHunters; i ++) {
    Hunter h = hunters[i];
    a2[h.x][h.y] = h.name;
}
```

Comment: So now that I have done it ( all of them are at 11,11 so i can't tell if there are really 5) I had the code to move them around, now i cant find a way to actually do it. It was placed in my hunter class, `x = x+1;` for example, how do I replicate it now?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify what language you're using.  That would help a bit.
At a minimum, try removing the "static" keyword from your property definitions.

In C#, your Hunter class might look like

```
public class Hunter
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public String name;
    public Hunter(int newX, int newY, String newName)
    {
        x = newX;
        y = newY;
        name = newName;
    }
}
```

You create new Hunters using `Hunter h1 = new Hunter(11, 11, "H");`.  Once created, you can do whatever with it.

You may want to do some reading up on Object Oriented Programming - see [Intro to OOP](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/OOP_Concepts_and_manymore.aspx) esp sections 4.3 - 4.5 (they're short)